# PostgreSQL - Optimizing query performance

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database, query-optimization

I'm analyzing my queries performance using New Relic and this one in particular is taking a long time to complete:

```
 SELECT  "events".*
 FROM "events"
 WHERE ("events"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND
        "events"."eventable_id" = $? AND
        "events"."eventable_type" = $? OR
        "events"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND
        "events"."eventable_id" IN (SELECT "flow_recipients"."id" FROM "flow_recipients" WHERE "flow_recipients"."contact_id" = $?) AND "events"."eventable_type" = $?)
ORDER BY "events"."created_at" DESC
LIMIT $? OFFSET $?
```

Sometimes this query takes more than 8 seconds to be completed, and I can't understand why. I have taken a look at the query explain, but I'm not sure I can understand it:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my indexes? Is there something I can optimize? How could I further investigate what's going on?

I suspect that the fact that I'm using SELECT events.* instead of selecting only the columns I'm interested could have some impact, but I'm using a LIMIT of 15, so I'm not sure it would impact that much.

[EDIT]
I have an index on created_at column and another index on eventable_id and eventable_type columns. Apparently, this second index is not being used, and I don't know why.

Comment: You are practically doing a join on "eventable_id" (in the form of a sub-select). Do you have an index on this column? Join columns are good candidates for indexes.

Comment: Yes, I have an index on created_at column and another index on eventable_id and eventable_type. Apparently, this second index is not being used, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the long execution time is

1. that the optimizer hopes it can find enough matching rows quickly by scanning all rows in the sorting order and picking out those that match the condition, but the executor has to scan 630835 rows until it finds enough matching rows.
2. For every row that is being examined, the subselect is executed.

You should rewrite that `OR` to a `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
  AND eventable_id = $?
  AND eventable_type = $?
UNION
SELECT * FROM events e
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
  AND eventable_type = $?
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM flow_recipients f
              WHERE f.id = e.eventable_id
                AND f.contact_id = $?);
```

This query does the same thing if `events` has a primary key.

Useful indexes depend on the execution plan chosen, but these ones *might* be good:

```
CREATE INDEX ON events (eventable_type, eventable_id)
   WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;

CREATE INDEX ON flow_recipients (contact_id);
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation! Thanks :)